# Testing Ruby code snippets with eval() in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, binding, eval, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I would like to use `eval()` in Ruby 1.9 to test little pieces of ruby code in an interactive way. A long time ago (around Ruby 1.4) I found a neat script on the internet providing this functionality. Here is simplified and reduced version:

```
line = ''
$stdout.sync = true
print "ruby> "
while true
    input = gets
    if input
        line = input 
    else
        break if line == ''
    end
    begin
        print eval(line).inspect, "\n"
    rescue ScriptError, StandardError
        $! = 'exception raised' unless $!
        print "ERROR: ", $!, "\n"
    end
    break if not input
    line = ''
    print "ruby> "
end
```

I was able to do something like:

```
ruby> str = "a:b:c"
"a:b:c"
ruby> str.split /:/
["a", "b", "c"]
ruby>
```

This script works fine up to Ruby 1.8, however not anymore in 1.9 due to the changed semantics of `eval()`. Now I'm not able to make local variables like `str` anymore. Instead I get the following obvious message:

```
ERROR: undefined local variable or method `str' for main:Object
```

Is there a way to fix or bypass this behaviour of `eval()`? I've read something about bindings but I'm not sure how to do that here.

Of course there is `irb` but in that tool I can't use the pound sign like in `"abc#{var}def"`. If I try then `irb` comments out the whole line.

Comment: `"abc#{var}def"` works in irb for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working code:

```
$stdout.sync = true
while true
  print "ruby> "
  input = gets
  break unless input
  begin
    p eval(input, TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
  rescue ScriptError, StandardError
    puts "ERROR: #{$! || "exception raised"}"
  end
end
```

I changed many thing in the code to make it clean, but the point is the scope of the `eval`. It was being executed inside the `begin` block. All local variables defined by the `eval` were being created inside the `begin` block and were being destroyed when the `begin` ends, after each iteration. The constant `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` returns the scope of the top level (outside everything). It makes the eval execute the code in a place that will not be destroyed (until the program ends). You can also get the scope of any place using the method `binding` and send it as the second argument of `eval`.

```
def get_a_binding
  x = 42
  return binding
end

x = 50
scope = get_a_binding
eval("print x", scope) #=> prints 42
```